# How to loop through multiple a tags and return in variable?

Tags: jquery, loops, variables

I'm developing a list that contains tags, each list can contain one or more tags.

I'm trying to loop through the an existing list with multiple "a" tags per list, get the href value and the text of each and return both as one variable to use in a new list. I will replace the existing list with the new by finally hiding the existing list. See how I've attempted below. Should this work? Am I missing something obvious?

```
$('existing-list-element').each(function(){

var testVar = $('a').each(function(){
    var thisText = $(this).text();
    var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');
    var newTag = $('<a href="'+ thisHref +'">'+ thisText +'</a>')
    return newTag
});
var newList = $('<div class="new-list-element"><span class="tags">'+ testVar +'</span></div>')
$(this).hide(); //hides the existing list
$('container-for-both-lists').append(newList);});
```

Comment: `testVar` is the collection returned by `$('a')`. `each` doesn't work like that. You are probably looking for the `map` method which returns an array. Also you shouldn't concatenate jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop the anchors of your list, right now you're looping all anchors each list iteration, also, build an html string of all your new anchors and append it all at once, try:

```
$('existing-list-element').each(function() {
    var tags = "";
    $("a", this).each(function() {
        var thisText = $(this).text();,
            thisHref = this.href,
            newTag = '<a href="'+ thisHref +'">'+ thisText +'</a>'

        tags += newTag;
    });

    var newList = '<div class="new-list-element"><span class="tags">'+ tags +'</span></div>';
    $(this).hide(); //hides the existing list
    $('container-for-both-lists').append(newList);
});
```

Comment: @undefined -- Ahh damn, lemme change that to a string real quick. There we go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys, checking this now!